# Plural of "learning"

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the plural of *learning*? Is it *learnings*?

Comment: related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242843/learnings-to-talk-about-things-that-were-learned-but-that-were-not-taught

Answer (score 18):

Actually, *learnings* sounds terrible to native American English speakers.  I never heard of it being used at all until I worked with people from India.

*Learnings*, *informations*, and *the needful* were all new to me, and I'm not even sure if they are correct.

Looking up the noun in the *Oxford English Dictionary* and in other dictionaries, I see no text referring to *learnings* at all, so I'm not sure if it is the correct plural of *learning*.  I've *never* heard it spoken by English speakers born in America.

Here is another discussion on it:  http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081013100405AAb3jdp

Comment: *Learning* is usually uncountable in American English ... we don't pluralize it.

Comment: It also sounds terrible to native Australian English speakers and I expect that this will also be true for New Zealanders, Canadians and in the UK.

Comment: I am a native American English speaker and see no issue with "learnings." It is similar to other pluralized gerund forms such as "beginnings" or "drawings". A singular learning is a fact that has been acquired as knowledge. As I can know many facts, it follows that I have many learnings.

Comment: I am also a native American English speaker, and "learnings" sounds fine.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the plural of *learning* is *learnings*. It appears in established expressions like *new learnings* (a medical term).

I don't think it's very widely used, and I think most uses I could read are just mistakes. The term is voguish, and it sounds good, but I don't see the need for it in *“Key learnings from X”* when you can just say *“Key lessons from X”*.

Comment: Isn't *knowledge* the term that is used?

Answer (score 11):

If you're taking 'learning' as a gerund (the noun version of the present participle), then I don't really think that a plural of it is a coherent notion.

If you take 'learning' to be 'a thing learned or to be learned', it is a bit new to most people, and sounds like a neologism by advertisers or people who couldn't remember the word 'lesson' or 'fact'. In that case, yes, the appropriate plural would be 'learnings'.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting case where "learning" can be either countable or uncountable depending on the context. If it is uncountable, it doesn't take a plural ending.

Let me give you a different word with a similar word: "time".

> There is plenty of time to get everything done.

Here "time" is a singular, because we are talking abstractly about time in general.

> I have these times available to meet with you: 9am, 10:30am and 2pm.

Here we use a plural because we are not talking about time in the broad abstract but specific individualized times.

So let's talk about learning.

> There is plenty of learning to be had in his grammar class.

Here we are talking about abstract learning in general, rather than individual items of learning.

> In his class I learned how to conjugate verbs and decline nouns. Each of these learnings together helped me toward mastery of the language.

This terminology while awkward to many grammarians has become a kind of jargon phrase. For example this book is called ["Essential Learnings in Mathematics."](https://books.google.com/books?id=R5UNAAAACAAJ&dq=%22learnings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFh5nXg5zMAhWPCD4KHUIzDUEQ6AEIKDAC). This spike can be seen in the [ngram of the word's usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=learnings&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clearnings%3B%2Cc0). Which shows it peaking in the 1960s.

However, it does have less buzzwordy usage too. There a few citations of it such as [ones referenced here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118379/first-use-of-learnings) including this from Shakespeare:

> Shakespeare Cymbeline (1623) i. i. 43 The king..Puts to him all the
>   Learnings that his time Could make him the receiuer of.

According to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/learnings), there are older citations where "learnings" is used to mean the compliment: teaching. In times past "learn" could be used to mean "teach" as in "I learned him how to ride a bike." Sounds awful to the modern ear, but it was one of the meanings of the word in the past.

There is a lot more at that wiktionary link.

Comment: I think that's it, it's not countable.  It's a verb, the act gaining information.  Something that has been learned through learning is knowledge.  Looking at it as a noun or even a plural noun is oddly awkward.

Comment: "Learn" is a verb, "Learning" is a special kind of noun called a gerund. (There is a related word spelled the same which is a present participle, where it is an adjective, as in "stack exchange is a learning environment.")